# jhipster Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request

Tags: jhipster

I set up a basic jhipster app with postgresql database and everything ok but when trying to login I get this error **Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request**. The request parameters the app is sending are these

```
password    admin
username    admin
```

I am using the default config.
What I am missing here?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this issue nor have I ever seen it with a JHipster project.  What auth type are you using, and do you have a proxy between the user and the app?

Comment: Currently using jwt for authentication and no, there is no proxy. I am going to try the session authentication and I will let you know if that solves the problem

Answer (score 5):

After a while I found the problem and was totally my fault. If you ever ever ever get this error message you have a jenkins process running in port 8080. Looks like jhipster somehow checks if there is any (java ?) application running on port 8080 and since jenkins was up on that port... Again my bad.